# Get the tax for google analytics with in-app-billing

Tags: android, google-analytics, payment, in-app-billing, android-billing

I have an app with in-app-billing & google analytics setup and now I want to track my transactions and purchases from within the app. My issue is that I can't get my head around how I'm supposed to get the tax for the transaction.

The tax is different in each country (based on the credit-card i think) if I'm not mistaken so there should be a way to get it programmatically. I am using Googles in-app-billing api v3 and Analytics SDK for Android V4.

I dunno, I might be missing something obvious. Help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you need to provide the tax amount when you are submitting your transaction hit. Check the [ecommerce tracking guide](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/ecommerce). You can set the tax amount using [setTax](http://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/project/2013/271/g1327125/android-studio/sdk/extras/google/google_play_services/docs/reference/com/google/android/gms/analytics/HitBuilders.TransactionBuilder.html#setTax(double)) method on the HitBuilders.TransactionBuilder. Since taxes differ based on many thing (like the address zip code in US or the product category) Analytics can deduct the tax based on location alone. Your app needs to provide this with the transaction.